# Fetching index avg fragmentation for each database

Tags: sql-server, index-tuning

i am  beginner and writing a query  to fetch avg fragmentation in percent to rebuild indexex for db i used cursor but  i m able to bring for one database so how to include for all database using outer cursor excluding master database ... please help me to put outer cursor to bring for all database exlcuding  master

my query is  like this

```
 DECLARE @TableName VARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @schema VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @indexName VARCHAR(255)
Declare @avgfrag int
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(500)

DECLARE TableCursor CURSOR FOR

SELECT schema_name(t.schema_id)                           AS [Schema],
       object_name(ps.object_id)                          AS [Table],
       i.name                                             AS [Index],
       --ps.Index_type_desc                                 AS IndexType,
       convert(TINYINT,ps.avg_fragmentation_in_percent)   AS [AvgFrag%]
       --convert(TINYINT,ps.avg_page_space_used_in_percent) AS [AvgSpaceUsed%],
       --ps.record_count                                    AS RecordCnt,
       --ps.fragment_count                                  AS FragmentCnt
FROM     sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(db_id(db_name()),NULL,NULL,NULL,'DETAILED') ps -- Faster option: SAMPLED
         INNER JOIN sys.indexes i
           ON ps.object_id = i.object_id
              AND ps.index_id = i.index_id
         INNER JOIN sys.tables t 
           ON ps.object_id = t.object_id

WHERE  ps.avg_fragmentation_in_percent >=1

ORDER BY ps.avg_fragmentation_in_percent desc




OPEN TableCursor

FETCH NEXT FROM TableCursor INTO @schema,@TableName,@indexname,@avgfrag
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
SET @sql = 'ALTER INDEX  '+ @indexname + ' ON ' + @Schema  +'.'+ @tablename + ' REBUILD ' --+' with (online=on)'
print @SQL +'   '+ convert(varchar,@avgfrag)

EXEC (@sql)

FETCH NEXT FROM TableCursor INTO @schema,@TableName,@indexname,@avgfrag
END
CLOSE TableCursor
DEALLOCATE TableCursor
GO
```

Comment: Why are you writing your own stuff ? Use the proven and tested maintenance solution - https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-index-and-statistics-maintenance.html

Comment: Look in to Aaron Bertrand's sp_MSforeachdb, https://sqlblog.org/2020/08/04/reliable-flexible-replacement-sp_msforeachdb

Comment: Agree with Kin. Ola's stuff is great. But is you did want to do it yourself you would need to encapsulate everything you have as string (with USE dbname), execute it in another cursor looping through DBname.

Comment: I encourage people who write their own code specially if you are a beginner this will give you confidence, you always have option to use already tested one. You should use While loop as mentioned in [this code](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Script-to-Rebuild-and-60d0ab15). Just get the idea from the code and create you own.I mostly prefer to use while loop as compared to cursor

Comment: Enlightening - [Bad Habits to Kick : Thinking a WHILE loop isn't a CURSOR](https://sqlblog.org/2012/01/26/bad-habits-to-kick-thinking-a-while-loop-isnt-a-cursor)

Comment: HA!!..not required. I said *I mostly prefer*.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ I would call this as nitpicking I still stick to point that in most cases a while loop is better than cursor, we always have to edgy cases. That is why i added in last the word mostly.

Comment: @kin  i have not seen the ola.hallengre article yea there might be  so many different script but i just want basic scripts to  rebuild indexes that have higher fragmenattion more than 30 . i could have used that but without knowing whats in script i dont wanna use  since i dont know the consequences and . i m using this script hardly for 10 databases and even thats not to big . so i wanna initiate myself . and  this scripts run perfect for me for one database now i just wanna add it for  mulitple db  to run on job .

Comment: @Shanky Yeah, removing my comments.

Comment: @shanky just curious why you believe while loop is better than cursor? What is better? performance? syntax? They both do the same thing (row-by-row) but cursors have more options(FAST_FORWARD, READ_ONLY, etc)

Comment: sure its good to learn to write your own code, but not to deploy it to prod if you're a beginner.

Answer (score 1):

This script will loop through all databases and execute the selective reindex script.

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET NOCOUNT ON;

declare @dbname nvarchar(100)
declare @reindexcommand varchar(max)

DECLARE dbreindex CURSOR
FOR SELECT quotename([name]) from sys.databases
WHERE database_id <>2
AND is_read_only = 0


open dbreindex
while(1=1)
    begin
        FETCH NEXT FROM dbreindex        
        INTO @dbname

        IF @@FETCH_STATUS < 0 
        BREAK  
        SELECT 'Rebuilding/Reorganizing indexes on '+@dbname+' Starting a t'+convert(varchar(50),getdate())+''
        SELECT ''

        set @reindexcommand = '
USE '+ @dbname + ';
SET NOCOUNT ON   
DECLARE @reorg_frag_thresh   float   SET @reorg_frag_thresh   = 10.0
DECLARE @rebuild_frag_thresh float   SET @rebuild_frag_thresh = 30.0
DECLARE @fill_factor         tinyint SET @fill_factor         = 80
DECLARE @report_only         bit     SET @report_only         = 0 
DECLARE @objectid       int
DECLARE @indexid        int
DECLARE @dbid           int
DECLARE @partitioncount bigint
DECLARE @databasename   nvarchar(130)
DECLARE @schemaname     nvarchar(130) 
DECLARE @objectname     nvarchar(130) 
DECLARE @indexname      nvarchar(130) 
DECLARE @partitionnum   bigint
DECLARE @partitions     bigint
DECLARE @frag           float
DECLARE @command        nvarchar(4000)
DECLARE @intentions     nvarchar(4000)
DECLARE @table_var      
TABLE(objectid     int,
indexid      int,
partitionnum int,
frag         float) 
SET @databasename = '''+@dbname+'''
SET @dbid = DB_ID()
INSERT INTO    @table_var
SELECT    [object_id] AS objectid,
[index_id] AS indexid,
[partition_number] AS partitionnum, 
[avg_fragmentation_in_percent] AS frag
FROM    sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats (@dbid, NULL, NULL , NULL, ''LIMITED'')
WHERE    [avg_fragmentation_in_percent] > @reorg_frag_thresh 
AND    index_id > 0 


DECLARE partitions CURSOR 
FOR    SELECT * FROM @table_var 
OPEN partitions 
WHILE (1=1) 
BEGIN    
        FETCH NEXT FROM partitions        
        INTO @objectid, @indexid, @partitionnum, @frag     
        IF @@FETCH_STATUS < 0 
        BREAK     
        SELECT      @objectname = QUOTENAME(o.[name]),        
                    @schemaname = QUOTENAME(s.[name])   
        FROM        sys.objects AS o WITH (NOLOCK)            
        JOIN sys.schemas as s WITH (NOLOCK)                
        ON s.[schema_id] = o.[schema_id]    
        WHERE       o.[object_id] = @objectid     
        SELECT      @indexname = QUOTENAME([name])    
        FROM        sys.indexes WITH (NOLOCK)    
        WHERE       [object_id] = @objectid 
        AND         [index_id] = @indexid     
        SELECT      @partitioncount = count (*)    
        FROM        sys.partitions WITH (NOLOCK)    
        WHERE       [object_id] = @objectid 
        AND         [index_id] = @indexid     
        SET @intentions = @databasename + N''.'' + @schemaname + N''.'' + @objectname + N''.'' + @indexname + N'':'' 
        SET @intentions = ''====='' + @intentions       
        SET @intentions = @intentions + N'' FRAGMENTATION: '' + CAST(@frag AS nvarchar) + N''%''      
        IF @frag < @rebuild_frag_thresh 
            BEGIN        
                SET @intentions = @intentions + N'' OPERATION: REORGANIZE''         
                SET @command = N''ALTER INDEX '' + @indexname + N'' ON ''+ @databasename + N''.''+@schemaname + N''.'' + @objectname + N'' REORGANIZE''    
            END    
        IF @frag >= @rebuild_frag_thresh 
            BEGIN        
                SET @intentions = @intentions + N'' OPERATION: REBUILD''        
                SET @command = N''ALTER INDEX '' + @indexname + N'' ON '' + @databasename + N''.''+ @schemaname + N''.'' + @objectname + N'' REBUILD''    
            END    
        IF @partitioncount > 1 
            BEGIN        
                SET @intentions = @intentions + N'' PARTITION: '' + CAST(@partitionnum AS nvarchar(10))       
                SET @command = @command + N'' PARTITION='' + CAST(@partitionnum AS nvarchar(10))    
            END    
        IF @frag >= @rebuild_frag_thresh AND @fill_factor > 0 AND @fill_factor < 100 
            BEGIN        
                SET @intentions = @intentions + N'' FILL FACTOR: '' + CAST(@fill_factor AS nvarchar)       
                SET @command = @command + N'' WITH (FILLFACTOR = '' + CAST(@fill_factor AS nvarchar) + '')''    
            END     
        IF @report_only = 0 
            BEGIN        
                SET @intentions = @intentions + N'' EXECUTING: '' + @command        
                PRINT @intentions        
                EXEC (@command)    
            END 
        ELSE 
            BEGIN        
                PRINT @intentions    
            END  
        END 
CLOSE partitions
DEALLOCATE partitions
'
    --print @reindexcommand
    EXEC (@reindexcommand) 
    SELECT'***************************************************************'


    end

close dbreindex
deallocate dbreindex
go
```